# Angular is loading items twice for a short period

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

The only time it loads the right items is on first page load. Then, on every refresh it loads the items twice for half of second, like you see in the GIF.

My code is dead simple, it feels wrong to post it, but i will. I tried `ng-cloak` on `table`, but nothing is changed. Any ideas why it's doing this and how can i make it stop?

```
    var RefreshData = function () {
        Machine.getAllMachines().then(function (response) {
            machineList.allMachines = response.data
            console.log('RefreshData 6 sec', machineList.allMachines)
        })
        setTimeout(RefreshData, 6000)
    }
    RefreshData()


<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ip</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th> Processor</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in machineList.allMachines">
            <td>{{item.Ip}}</td>
            <td>ONLINE</td>
            <td>{{item.Department}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Processor}}</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Update**: 
Recreated the loop with button click and it's the same effect. So the timeout is not the problem.

[image]

Comment: are you using `$scope.$watch` at all?

Comment: try using angular $timeout instead of `setTimeout` and move it inside the `then()` callback

Comment: @MaxPaymar no, i'm using  `var machineList = this`, and no $watch

Comment: @charlietfl tried `$timeout(RefreshData, 6000))` inside the `then()` callback, and no change.

Comment: What if you add machineList.allMachines = {}; as the first command inside Machine.getAllMachines().then(function (response) { ? Does that fix the problem?

Comment: @papakias no it doesn't, but i got an idea. I will call the method from a button and try to see it it does the same thing onclick.

Comment: instead if replacing `machineList.allMachines` each refresh, try using `extend` to update it instead, i.e. `angular.extend(machineList.allMachines, response.data);`

Comment: @Claies I replaced all the code insde `.then()` with `machineList.allMachines = [];                 angular.extend(machineList.allMachines, response.data); ` and it's the same behaviour.

Comment: As we've mentioned over at the angularjs github (see: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15916) this is not really a bug in AngularJS. What you're trying to do shouldn't be a problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/aXciHkslKatBBdzlTJqT?p=preview . I'd profile your angularjs application and try to get a visual on what's happening on every digest cycle. There could be a single $watch (not related to this part of your app) which is causing a slow digest cycle. If you can reproduce it in a plunkr (as I 've asked over at the github issue) I can have a look at it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to recreate the glitch in many ways from scratch, but failed. So i decided to rip my app to pieces until it will stop doing it.
So after stripping it to the bone i started cutting classes, and it turned out that Bootstrap **`table-hover`** it was doing this lol xD!  It seems a bit weird, but it's the only thing i changed in the end and it works fine now.

> So if anyone has this problem try remove **`table-hover`**

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
      var RefreshData = function () {
            machineList.allMachines = [];
            Machine.getAllMachines().then(function (response) {
                machineList.allMachines = response.data
                console.log('RefreshData 6 sec', machineList.allMachines)
            })
            setTimeout(RefreshData, 6000)
        }
        RefreshData()
```

Comment: Tried, and it's the same thing. I added an Update on the question, not related to your answer though.

Answer (score -1):

You have basically created an infinite loop, by recursively calling the method RefreshData every 6 seconds. First you invoke the method using RefreshData(), and then from the body of the method you use setTimeout(RefreshData, 6000), which will invoke RefreshData after 6000 milliseconds.

If your intention was to trigger a digest cycle after retrieving data async, then your code should look like this:

```
var RefreshData = function () {
    Machine.getAllMachines().then(function (response) {
        $timeout(function() { machineList.allMachines = response.data; });
    });       
};
RefreshData();
```

Be sure to inject the $timeout provider.

Comment: It's generaly not a good idea to use setTimout. But in the OP's question the setTimeout is not causing any troubles (at least nog by looking at the shared code). As mentioned by @charlietfl , the digest cycle is triggered by using $q (I'm guessing he's using $q, but can't tell for sure). You can try it out https://plnkr.co/edit/aXciHkslKatBBdzlTJqT?p=preview